# How to pass subcommand back into bash completion?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-completion

I've written a command which could be compared to `time` or `timeout` in that it's used at the start of the line as a prefix to any other bash command. My question is, how do I convince my bash completion script/rule to run the normal completion for the subcommand - exactly as it would do if my prefix command wasn't present?

E.g. the current situation is:

```
$ svn [tab]     - lists the svn commands
```

and:

```
$ mything svn [tab]  - my completion needs to hand-over to svn's completion
```

but `svn` in the example above may be pretty much *any* bash command.

Comment: Does it need to return to yourthing after svn's completion? If not, exec svn.

Comment: And of course I've answered my own question!

If I do `"complete -p | grep time"` then I can see how that command does it - I just need to define a completion rule as follows:

`complete -o filenames -F _command myprefix`

Simple! Now I just need to figure out how on Earth `time` ensures that this completion rule is set up in the first place...

Comment: I think all I actually have to do is put my `complete` line into an otherwise empty file, called `mything`, and install (copy) it into `/etc/bash_completion.d/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comments above, I've answered my own question!

After doing `"complete -p | grep time"`, we can see how that command does it - you just need to define a completion rule as follows:

```
complete -o filenames -F _command mything
```

and put it into an otherwise empty a file called `/etc/bash_completion.d/mything`. When you open a new bash terminal, you should then find that your `mything` command can complete any subcommands in the normal manner.